# How to connect/query HSQL database outside application?

Tags: hibernate, database-connection, hsqldb

I am using embedded HSQL as a database for my Java application. And connecting to the database via Hibernate, below are the hibernate.cfg.xml file entries,

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb;shutdown=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
```

I am able to connect to the database via my java application, hibernate is automatically creating tables, also inserting data into tables as i can see it in my application when i query tables via application.

But when i try to access my database via SQL Workbench, its not showing me any of the tables. It does get connected with below properties,

```
Driver - org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver  
URL - jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb
UserName - sa
Password -
```

After getting connected it shows below schemas,

> *,  INFORMATION_SCHEMA,  PUBLIC,  SYSTEM_LOBS

But when i fire select query for one of the tables it shows error as,

> user lacks privilege or object not found: table_name [SQL State=42501, DB Errorcode=-5501]

So are there any specific configurations i need to do to connect my embedded database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was providing wrong information in URL, to connect to file based HSQL database you have to provide URL as below if you are on windows,

> jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\Softwares\eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32\eclipse\testdb

Need to mention full path of the database file. Its working fine for me now.
Also for in-process file mode, only one connection can take place. Below link helped me to resolve the issue,
[HSQL jdbcConnection class Documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html)